# Is there a term for "an official text for how to handle certain scenarios"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I am compiling a book of checklists for myself and my team. These checklists will be indexed based on certain scenarios that they fix. For instance, under "Computer Won't Turn On", one might list "Is it plugged in?", "Does it need to be charged?", etc.

**Is there a term for such a thing?**

My immediate thought was "red book", but apparently that already has [devilish](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/red_book#English) and [communist](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Little_Red_Book#English) connotations.

Answer (score 2):

[Standard Operating Procedure (SOP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_operating_procedure) would be my first thought

Comment: Nice! Is there a variation on this that implies it's for recovering from an undesired situation, rather than that which seems to apply to all situations?

Comment: In many organizations, there could be an SOP for catastrophic failure.  In the event of a military vessel sinking, the highest rated surviving officer may be charged with destroying crypto assets, collecting/destroying charts, ensuring lifeboats are deployed for an orderly exit by the crew.  I'm sure it would all be heavily delegated, and the SOP will lay out _how_ to delegate those duties.  It's about standardization of _all_ procedures, not just what to do when everything is fine.

Answer (score 1):

A commonly accepted phrase for a book that deals with how to fix something that's gone wrong and which is both important and urgent is **emergency manual**. Interestingly, I can find no actual dictionary definition for it, although it's commonly understood and used almost universally—as by [Coastal California University](https://www.coastal.edu/emergency/EmergencyManual.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

I might suggest:

- [Guide](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/guide)

> A book, document, or display providing information on a subject or about a place.

- [Manual](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/manual)

> A book giving instructions or information.

If you want more specificity, you could try:

- Operating Manual
- Troubleshooting Guide

or similar modifications.

Comment: Probably needs to be more specific: Process Manual; Debugging Guide; etc.

Comment: @JamesRandom good suggestion.  It does seem the OP wants more specificity.  "Operating Manual" might be my choice, or "Troubleshooting Guide".  (Answer amended:)